# Number groups with 0 as delimiter

Tags: regex

There's a long natural number that can be grouped to smaller numbers by the 0 (zero) delimiter.
Example: `4201100370880`

This would divide to `Group1: 42`, `Group2: 110`, `Group3: 370880`
There are 3 groups, groups never start with 0 and are at least 1 char long. Also the last groups is "as is", meaning it's not terminated by a tailing 0.

This is what I came up with, but it only works for certain inputs (like 420110037880):

`(\d+)0([1-9][0-9]{1,2})0([1-9]\d+)`

This shows I'm attempting to declare the 2nd group's length to min2 max3, but I'm thinking the correct solution should not care about it. If the delimiter was non-numeric I could probably tackle it, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Why "`Group3: 370880`" and not "`Group3: 37, Group4: 880`"?

Comment: Could you explain the AI involved?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sorry, I've been looking at the problem for a while now and it slipped my mind to specify that the number of groups is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
^(.*?)0(?!0)(.*?)0(?!0)(.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/j21_NmSE3etLbbH1)

Answer (score 1):

All right, factoring in comment information, try splitting on a regex (this may vary based on what language you're using - `.split(/.../)` in JavaScript, `preg_split` in PHP, etc.)

The regex you want to split on is: `0(?!0)`. This translates to "a zero that is not followed by a zero". I believe this will solve your splitting problem.

If your language allows a `limit` parameter (PHP does), set it to 3. If not, you will need to do something like this (JavaScript):

```
result = input.split(/0(?!0)/);
result = result.slice(0,2).concat(result.slice(2).join("0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works:

`(\d+?)0(?!0)` with the `g` modifier

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/rS4dE5

For only three matches, you can do:

`(\d+?)0(?!0)(\d+?)0(?!0)(.*)`